# Flot stacked chart bar width like line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I tried to make flot stacked chart to input data in array x1,x2,x3... and y1,y2,y3...

My line chart data is made like that so I duplicated its js and did some changes but the width of bar still same as line chart. Any advise?

http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/67/

Comment: The problem is that you can't change the width of the lines?

Comment: I did changed it to 0.8 but it seem it was too small when I saw p_strand's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `barWidth: 0.4`. Since you are using Dates on the xaxis, the numeric values between `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and so on, will be relatively large values. If you wish the bars to be significantly wider than the axis lines, you would have to set `barWidth` to something like:

```
 barWidth:1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15 //Half month: 1000 ms * 60 sec *60 min * 24 hour * 15 days
```

I have created a fork from your jsfiddle example where I have modified the barWidth:

http://jsfiddle.net/6TaQt/1

Comment: Specifically, this is because for time series charts, the x-axis data is actually in milliseconds, and barWidth is measured in x-axis units. From the [Flot API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt): "For instance, for time series the unit is milliseconds so 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 produces bars with the width of a day."

Comment: Thanks. I did changed it to 0.8 but it seem  too small. :D